# How can I use hapi version safe or as generic?

Tags: java, c#, hapi, nhapi

I have this ugly code below for hl7 message seen here. The code runs for varied versions of HL7 listeners. For one system I receive in v2.3 but for the other one I get in v2.5

As you can notice the job is almost same for all versions. But the base of ACK is `message` and I can't call `getMsa1_AcknowledgementCode` method without explicitly casting to exact HL7 version,and there isn't a common `ACK` class among them. By this dummy diagram I tried to present the problem. (I know there are some other elements ,such as AbstractMessage,Group...)

[image]

And for first two the method name is `getMsa1_AcknowledgementCode` but for v2.5 it has missing `e` letter and seems like `getMsa1_AcknowledgmentCode`.

Should I use reflection and find a method starts with the name `getMsa_Ack...` to check an Acknowledge message or is there any type safe and beautiful way for this purpose in hapi project?

Do not constrain yourself for ACK message while answering I wonder a better way for others as well.

```
MSH|^~\&|Vendor|VandorApp|Receiver|RCApp|201504241154||ACK|187718704|T|2.3|||AL|AL|TR
MSA|AA|187718704

        String result="AA";

        ca.uhn.hl7v2.model.Message hl7 = initiator.sendAndReceive(msg);

        if(hl7 instanceof ca.uhn.hl7v2.model.v231.message.ACK)
        {
            ca.uhn.hl7v2.model.v231.datatype.ID id= ((ca.uhn.hl7v2.model.v231.message.ACK)hl7).getMSA().getMsa1_AcknowledgementCode();
            result=id.getValue();               
        }else if (hl7 instanceof ca.uhn.hl7v2.model.v23.message.ACK)
        {
            ca.uhn.hl7v2.model.v23.datatype.ID id=  ((ca.uhn.hl7v2.model.v23.message.ACK)hl7).getMSA().getMsa1_AcknowledgementCode();
            result=id.getValue();               
        }else if( hl7 instanceof ca.uhn.hl7v2.model.v25.message.ACK)
        {
            ca.uhn.hl7v2.model.v25.datatype.ID id=  ((ca.uhn.hl7v2.model.v25.message.ACK)hl7).getMSA().getMsa1_AcknowledgmentCode();
            result=id.getValue();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

With C#, using nHAPI, I would do something similar to the following

```
PipeParser parser = new PipeParser();
IMessage hl7Message = parser.Parse(hl7);
IStructure msa = hl7Message.GetStructure("MSA");
IType ackCode = ((ISegment)msa).GetField(1)[0];
MessageBox.Show(((AbstractPrimitive)ackCode).Value);
```

You have to use a lot of the base structures, and I have assumed a number of the castings - as we are looking for a specific field (that we know are defined the same in the HL7 specs).

Comment: I have also C# code but casting exact types instead of this way.
Have you tried your code for both 2.2 and 2.5 versions.
When you use 2.5 message ackCode become `NHapi.Model.V25.Datatype.ID`, (it's also an AbstractPrimitive) but if you use 2.2 it becomes `NHapi.Base.Model.Varies` (v2.3 so) and it's not an AbstractPrimitive. This time you should cast to Varies.Unfortunately, It doesn't seem as a mutual solution. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: It varies for `Varies`  `(((ackCode as NHapi.Base.Model.Varies).Data as GenericPrimitive).Value)` . As you see we reached the value over Data variable. It cause variety.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just get the ack code (or any other field) while ignoring all the issues with HAPI's object model, you can use the `Terser`

```
public String getAckCode(Message message) throws HL7Exception {
    Segment msaSegment = (Segment)message.get("MSA");
    return Terser.get(msaSegment, 1, 0, 1, 1);
}
```